# Understanding React functional components that return mapped child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I spent quite a bit of time debugging an issue with state resetting itself in child components on every re-render. After eventually solving it I realized that I don't fully understand how React functional components and Array.map() work together, which is why I'm hoping that someone can shed some light on the issue I was having:

Let's say I have an `ItemWrapper` component that returns (among other things) an `ItemListA` component. `ItemListA` maps over an array and returns a list of `Item` components. Each `Item` component has its own state that changes on certain actions.

The way I did it at first:

```
const ItemWrapper = ({ items }) =>  {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
    const someFunction = value => setSomeState(value);

    ...

    const ItemListA = () => items.map(item =>
        <Item
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            callback={someFunction}
        />
    )

    ...

    return (
        <div>
            <ItemListA />
        </div>
    );
};
```

The problem: whenever the `someFunction` callback was invoked in one of the `Item` children, this caused `ItemWrapper` to re-render and reset the state of all of the other `Item` children.

Solved it by storing the item list in a local variable rather than a component:

```
const ItemWrapper = ({ items }) =>  {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
    const someFunction = value => setSomeState(value);

    ...

    const itemListB = items.map(item =>
        <Item
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            callback={someFunction}
        />
    );

    ...

    return (
        <div>
            {itemListB}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I don't feel like I fully understand what's going on here. My guess would be that storing the item list in a functional component somehow made it so that the `ItemListA` component and its children (with the exception of the one that triggered the callback - no idea why) were destroyed and then rebuilt whenever the `ItemWrapper` component was re-rendered, meaning that there was no trace left of their previous state. Is it because `ItemListA` is a function and every re-render creates a new reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because ItemListA is a function and every re-render creates a new reference?

Yep, that's pretty much it.

When figuring out what changes to make to the DOM, react compares the virtual dom before with the virtual dom afterwards, and looks for changes. Doing an exhaustive comparison would be expensive, so they make some assumptions to speed things up. One of those assumptions is that if a component's type has changed, then that entire subtree is assumed to have changed. (For more info see react's [article on reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html))

So in this case, react sees `ItemListA` from the first time, and `ItemListA` from the second time, and they are different component types. They look very similar to our eyes, but they're different references, which means they're different to react. So react has to unmount the old ones and mount the new ones.

With your second code, you're not creating a new type of component on every render, you're just creating an array with elements in it. The two arrays are different references, but that's ok since it's not a type of component.

Comment: Nitpicking just to be consistent with the [PropTypes defined in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), but it's an array of nodes, which is anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or another array (or fragment) containing these types. In OP's specific case, it is an array of elements.

Comment: Right you are! Updated.